# Работа с пакетами, зависимостями в GO. (go.mod, vendor, gopath)

Tags: golang, package

Помогите разобраться в данном вопросе, верно ли я понимаю:

- GOPATH и go.mod это 2 разных подхода для работы с зависимостями и
  вместе они не совместимы
- go.mod позволяет более безопасно
  работать с зависимостями т.к. он привязывается не просто к
  репозиторию пакета, а к конкретной версии этого репозитория
- vendor
  позволяет скачать все зависимости в каталог и их использовать, что
  делает проект автономным, vendor с go.mod и GOPATH напрямую не
  связаны.

Вроде в теории все понятно, не понятно на практике.

**Проблема 1**
Есть проект, в нем есть go.mod, в проекте подключен пакет `github.com/RobotsAndPencils/buford/payload`, в go.mod добавлен `github.com/RobotsAndPencils/buford`
если удалить go.mod при сборке проекта ругается так

```
D:\GoMy\src\github.com\RobotsAndPencils\buford\pushpackage\pushpackage.go:15:2: cannot find package "github.com/aai/gocrypto/pkcs7" in any of:
 D:\Go\src\github.com\aai\gocrypto\pkcs7 (from $GOROOT)
 D:\GoMy\src\github.com\aai\gocrypto\pkcs7 (from $GOPATH)
```

в GOPATH действительно нет данного пакета, но он есть в каталоге vendor, почему GO игнорит каталог вендор и как это связано с наличием файла go.mod мне не понятно.

**Проблема 2** в корне проекта есть несколько файлов *.go и они с разными пакетами, даже IDE на это обращает внимание

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соответственно при попытке скомпилить проект или запустить дебаг из IDE (goland) ругается что не может загрузить пакеты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в данном случаи помогает build c ключом -o (`go build *.go` в винде не пашет). В принципе можно было бы сказать, так устроен GO и разойтись, но я попробовал создать свой тестовый проект с такой структурой

```
test
|-pack
|    |-test.go (package test)
|-main.go (package main)
|-test.go (package test)
```

в main.go подключен package test в test.go ничего не подключено, IDE так же обращает внимание на multiple package, но при это он прекрасно собирается так `go build main.go` и можно дебажить в IDE, так в чем нюанс, почему один проект ругается, другой норм работает?